# Django: how to use custom manager in get_previous_by_FOO()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a simple model **MyModel** with a date field named **publication_date**. I also have a custom manager that filters my model based on this date field.

This custom manager is accessible by **.published** and the default one by **.objects**.

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.db import models

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        q = super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set()
        return q.filter(publication_date__lte=datetime.now()) 

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    publication_date = models.DateField(default=date.today())

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = MyModelManager()
```

This way, I got access to all objects in the admin but only to published ones in my views (using **MyModel.published.all()** queryset).

I also have

```
def get_previous(self):
    return self.get_previous_by_publication_date()

def get_next(self):
    return self.get_next_by_publication_date()
```

which I use in my templates: when viewing an object I can link to the previous and next object using

```
{{ object.get_previous }}
```

The problem is: this returns the previous object in the default queryset (**objects**) and not in my custom one (**published**).

I wonder how I can do to tell to this basic model functions (get_previous_by_FOO) to use my custom manager.
Or, if it's not possible, how to do the same thing with another solution.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**Edit**

The view is called this way in my urlconf, using object_detail from the generic views.

```
(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', object_detail,
    {
     'queryset': MyModel.published.all(),
     'slug_field': 'slug',
    },
    'mymodel-detail'
),
```

I'm using Django 1.2.

Comment: What queryset are you using in your views where you render the templates that contain {{ object.get_previous }}? Maybe the problem lies there

Comment: I use the generic views (django 1.2) with my custom manager. It don't uses this one.

Comment: Can you show us your urlconf? Where you reference the view

Comment: From django.db.models: base.py _get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD creates the queryset from qs = self.__class__._default_manager ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD() Django function (which is used by get_previous_by_publication_date...) uses the default_manager.

So I have adapted it to reimplement my own utility function

```
def _own_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(self, field, is_next):
    if not self.pk:
        raise ValueError("get_next/get_previous cannot be used on unsaved objects.")
    op = is_next and 'gt' or 'lt'
    order = not is_next and '-' or ''
    param = smart_str(getattr(self, field.attname))
    q = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (field.name, op): param})
    q = q|Q(**{field.name: param, 'pk__%s' % op: self.pk})
    qs = MyModel.published.filter(q).order_by('%s%s' % (order, field.name), '%spk' % order)
    try:
        return qs[0]
    except IndexError:

def get_previous(self):
    return self._own_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(MyModel._meta.fields[4], False)

def get_next(self):
    return self._own_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(MyModel._meta.fields[4], True)
```

This is not a very clean solution, as I need to hardcode the queryset and the field used, but at least it works.